# Add mysql dll reference to an auto compiling c# file

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am making a project without visual studio. Currently I have two files in the project.

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" src="Default.cs" inherits="foo" %>
```

Default.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public class foo : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

}
```

I have downloaded and installed the mysql connector msi. And I believe I can add the mysql reference using `csc Program.cs /r:mysql.dll`. Now I am stuck at two things:

- Where is the .dll file? (Edit: Nvm, found it in install directory)
- I am running the code from IIS by simply pointing the page to localhost:8080, I don't compile any thing. I want to keep things as simple and bare bones as possible. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather simple. I had to put the .dll file in /bin/ directory of my website. It picks up assemblies from that directory.